# Github Pages does not work properly with cyrillic custom domain

Tags: dns, github-pages, cname, cyrillic

So, I am trying to setup custom domain on github pages and my domain contains cyrillic letters, and I can't add custom domain:

[image]

But with english letters all ok:

[image]

Comment: It seems you need to input the encoded version (which I could have given you if you pasted a text and not an image), search for IDNA encoding or Punycode, you should get a string starting with `xn--`. But otherwise you are offtopic here.

Comment: Oh, yes! Thanks! You save my day, Punycode help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the IDNA convention:

> To prevent non-international domain names containing hyphens from being accidentally interpreted as Punycode, international domain name Punycode sequences have a so-called ASCII Compatible Encoding (ACE) prefix, "xn--", prepended.[2] Thus the domain name "bücher.tld" would be represented in ASCII as "xn--bcher-kva.tld".

Using python you could try `encode('idna')` to find what characters to use, for example:

```
$ python
>>> x = u'bücher.tld'
>>> x.encode('idna')
b'xn--bcher-kva.tld'
>>> x.encode('idna').decode('idna')
'bücher.tld'
```